# MySQL: Feed posts are displaying too many times

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently working with a group of 4 others on a little social networks. I'm currently working on the feed and i'm running into a little issue.

I basically have an idea of why the issue is happening but I don't have an idea of how I should fix it.

What I have is 2 tables. 1 table for the posts itself, (called `posts`) and one for the users friends (called `users_friends`).

**posts** Table:
[image: This is the posts table.]

**users_friends** Table:

[image: This is the users_friends table]

I `JOIN` these two tables so that I can display only the posts of users you are friends with.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
JOIN users_friends
ON posts.username = users_friends.friend 
OR posts.username = '{$db['username']}'
WHERE users_friends.user = '{$db['username']}'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

`$db['username']` = Logged In Users Username

Because my user, `shawn31313`, shows up twice in the `users_friends` table, each post is doubled. The results of using this query is:

[image]
I don't know how to fix this. This is my first time using `JOIN` and i'm fairly new to `MySQL` in general so i'm not sure what to do now. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some problem with your query . when i look at your database structure then i can see there is username column in post table . that username is for user who post the comment , right ? if is it so then you just have to check that that user is in your friend list or not .

you can do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM POSTs
WHERE USERNAME IN (SELECT FRIENDS FROM USER_FRIENDS WHERE USER = 'shawn31313' union all select 'shawn31313' )
```

More faster query will be :

```
SELECT *
FROM POSTs AS A INNER JOIN (SELECT FRIENDS FROM USER_FRIENDS WHERE USER = 'shawn31313' union all select 'shawn31313' ) AS B ON A.USERID   = B.FRIENDS
```

The logic is find all your friends and then find all the post of those .

Comment: None of the methods work. First of, all of the names are wrong. There is no `post` table...there is a `posts` table. And when I fix all of that, i get an empty results.

Comment: @Shawn31313 "shawn31313" is current user right ? so this user can see post of their firends , right ? but i can't see any post of "yitze" and "test123" in post table . thats way you are getting empty result .

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I need c:

Comment: @Shawn31313 I modified my ans . check it .

Comment: @Shawn31313 , is it helpful to you ?